# Quadratic Formula App Inventor 2

Tags: android, app-inventor

I am writing an app that solves the quadratic formula using MIT App Inventor 2

My plan was to create two versions of the formula (The "+" and the "-" of -b plus or minus square root of 4ac/2a) And after doing so I was given the "The operation negate cannot accept the arguments"

I am unsure if it is the "Neg" block that is causing the issue. I have used the beta version before and assumed that "Neg" replaced the - block.

Is it the neg block that is giving me problems or is it more than that?

Thank you for whoever takes the time to help with this.

Comment: http://appinventor.mit.edu/explore/ai2/support/blocks/math.html#neg is supposedly "Returns the negative of a given number.". If that doesn't work, maybe try a minus block with [0, b]

Comment: It may just be me but is there no "-" block? I have looked it up all over...I could just be silly.  I also tried the same thing but using "-1 x (get b) And got an error message saying "The operation * cannot accept the arguments: -1" when that was tried.

Comment: I've just seen app inventor for the first time (well, it's website) so I have no clue if thats really the case but what I linked you is a "-" block in AI2 according to the documentation. There is also a substract block that takes more than 1 argument

Comment: Yeah, I looked at that before in an attempt to find it. No dice. *Sigh* thanks anyway.

Comment: Please provide a screenshot of your blocks and do not forget to validate all values before doing a calculation. For example you can't multiply an empty string... It also helps to use *Do it* to find out what's going on...

Comment: see my answer in the [App Inventor forum](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/mitappinventortest/714ELte_qM4/zhWCeIxjtoAJ)